# ADF Inspector results

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm looking at analysing the quality of area learning with project tango. Is there anyway to save the results of the ADF inspector (quality and number of successful matches) or another method of obtaining results of how effective the area learning is?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no API to let you query the quality of ADF. But you can sort of derive the quality of ADF based on user's movement. If user has observed all directions of environment, then you could consider the ADF is somewhat decent.

Unity AreaDescriptionManagement example shows how to achieve that from the application level.